# Laravel with MySQL relationship foreign key not appearing

Tags: mysql, laravel

I just want to ask if it is normal that, in Laravel, everytime I use foreign key constraint the constraint icon key is not showing inside **MYSQL**? Also, inside index is not showing.

**Note:** this is just to clarify if I am doing it the wrong way. Please help amend. Thanks.

This is the image

[image]

**Schema:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('subject_name');
        $table->integer('Level_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: How did you specified the foreign key constrain?

Comment: Can you share the migration file for that table?

Comment: i have updated my question with schema

Comment: @Grace you did not define the foreign key in the migration

Comment: @Grace I don't see any constrains there.. but I think what the question is.

Comment: @HCK do u have the right way of doing it? can u post the answer if u don't mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a [Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) in Laravel, like this:

```php
class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the original post from where the comment is from.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Laravel does not define a relationship constrain in your database by default. This is not how Laravel handle relationships.

To specify one, you need to add the constrain in the migration, like the [documentation states](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints):

```php
Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');

    // Check this part:    
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
});
```

---

## Update:

I think than the actual version of the docs ([L5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)) has removed this part but in the [L5.0](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) you can see it:

Check this part:

> Let's imagine that a `User` model might have one `Phone`. We can
>   define this relation in Eloquent:
>
> ```php
> class User extends Model {
>
>     public function phone()
>     {
>         return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> The first argument passed to the `hasOne` method is the name of the
>   related model. Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve it
>   using Eloquent's dynamic properties:
>
> ```php
> $phone = User::find(1)->phone;
> ```
>
> The SQL performed by this statement will be as follows:
>
> ```php
> select * from users where id = 1
>
> select * from phones where user_id = 1
> ```
>
> **Take note that Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, Phone model is assumed to use a
>   user_id foreign key.**

As you can see in bold, this is how Laravel manages to get the relationship information.

Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30391476/7117697).

Comment: Thanks now constrain is appearing also with index thanks man.. but by the way why with my previous code i can still manage to save the data laravel allow it?

Answer (score 1):

[**From the documentation:**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#indexes)

> Laravel also provides support for creating foreign key constraints,
>   which are used to force referential integrity at the database level.
>   For example, let's define a user_id column on the  posts table that
>   references the id column on a users table:

An example using the default `users` table and a new `posts` table, defined:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

From this, you can see that `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');` is the definition of the column in the table `posts`,

Then, we need define the relationship of `user_id` to `users`:  `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');` defines the re